# Succeeding vs. Consecutive

Tags: word-difference

I wrote:

> To detect this position, we track the color changes of three squared regions in **consecutive** video frames.

I first used "Succeeding" instead of "consecutive" but as I didn't find much matches on google, I change it. What is the difference?

Also in the following sentence which is better?

> This rotation opens up a gap between two succeeding pallet cars where the side of the middle frame is visible.

I searched them in Longman, however still didn't find their exact difference

These are some examples from Longman

> It had rained for four **consecutive days**.
>
> Over **the succeeding weeks** things went from bad to worse.

Aren't these examples very close?

Comment: You could get this answer from a good dictionary.  If you have consulted a good dictionary, and it doesn't make the difference clear, please advise.

Comment: ***Succeeding*** in this context would mean ***following*** (coming ***after*** something else previously mentioned). The correct form should be *in **successive** frames*. Which is about twice as common as ***consecutive** frames*, but apart from that they're equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: @TRomano I mentioned examples I found in Longman, but can't distinguish their correct usages, and why I can't use "succeeding" in my first sentence.

Comment: Succeeding frames are not necessarily consecutive frames. Succeeding are those which come after.  Consecutive frames are adjacent frames. You may need to say both:  in consecutive succeeding frames.

Comment: @Ahmad: As implied perhaps by Longman's *rained for four consecutive days* example, we tend to favour ***consecutive*** when we want to emphasize that there are *no intervening periods/events*, and ***successive*** when we're more interested in conveying the sequence itself (in that particular order, specifically, *chronological*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*X is/are succeeding Y* if X comes after Y.  There has to be a Y, express or implied.

*X are consecutive* if the occur "in a row" or right after each other.  If you are talking about *X in consecutive Y*, X appears somewhere in that row, but it could be in the middle or at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, then succeeding needs a reference point. *succeeding weeks* should mean the weeks that came after a time

Comment: Right, the default time if not specified would likely be 'now'.